# Flutter count items in list

Tags: flutter, dart

Есть

```
 List<Item> items = [];
```

добавляю `item` используя функцию:

```
Future addItems(Item item) async {
items.add(item);
}
```

Как можно вывести количество определенного `item` в листе с последующим изменением?

Comment: `количество определенного item`, поподробнее пожалуйста объясните.

Comment: я имел ввиду, при добавлении item, сам item разный. в лист добавляется так [item 1, item1, item2, item3, item4, item4, item4] и.тд. Нужно отобразить кол во item4 и item1. если добавить или удалить item4 то отображаемое кол во менялось.

Answer (score 0):

Ну например так, если правильно понял:

```
void main() {
  List<Item> items = [];
  List<Item> temp = [];

  items.add(Item(4));

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    items.add(Item(i));
  }

  items.add(Item(4));

  items.forEach((v) => print(v.id));

  temp.addAll(items.where((v) => v.id == 1 || v.id == 4));

  print("---------");

  temp.forEach((v) => print(v.id));
}

class Item {
  final int id;

  Item(this.id);
}
```